# PHP alternative of "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256" from Java

Tags: php, sha256, hmac, pbkdf2

I need to generate in PHP the same hash as as the `PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256` algorithm generates in Java.

I did some research and found two functions that seem to be connected to `PBKDF2` and `HMAC`:

- hash_pbkdf2 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php
- hash_hmac - http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

What PHP functions should I use? Is it even possible with native PHP functions?

**Edit #1**

My Java code, the same result I need achieve in PHP

```
public static byte[] derivateKey(char[] password, byte[] salt, int iterations, int keyLengthBits) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
            PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keyLengthBits);
            SecretKey key = skf.generateSecret(spec);
            byte[] res = key.getEncoded();
            return res;

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not create hash", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think `hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $key)` is what you want, but I'm not positive -- try it out.

Comment: You should first one with 'sha256' as the 1st argument of this function.

Comment: Please post an input and output pair from the Java function.

Comment: Can you post an example password and the result of its hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java code you've provided is basically [`hash_pbkdf2()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_pbkdf2). You just need to pass the correct params:

```
function derivateKey($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits)
{
    return hash_pbkdf2(
        'sha256',
        $password,
        $salt,
        $iterations,
        $keyLengthBits / 8,
        true
    );
}
```

Obviously, PHP's `hash_pbkdf2()` accepts the hash algorithm as a parameter, but the potentially tricky differences are these:

- It doesn't comply with [RFC 2898](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) in that its length is applied *after* hex-encoding, so that last parameter must be set to `true` to make it consistent with the spec.
- It accepts the output length in bytes instead of bits (hence why we divide by 8 above).

The only thing I'm not sure about is what `key.getEncoded()` does in your sample code ... there's no encoding algorithm specified anywhere.
I found some docs suggesting it is supposed to be RAW, so the example I'm providing should match it. If it doesn't, you'll have to encode it yourself.

Comment: in my case I had to base64_decode the salt key I found in the db and base64_decode the result to get the hash stored in the db