# PBKDF2 algorithm for both Java and PHP

Tags: java, php, pbkdf2

I have a website. This website uses PBKDF2 for user password encryption. I have to write login code with Java. I googled PBKDF2 algorithm for Java. But, Java and PHP results different.

Java code is

```
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Hash {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var password = "test".toCharArray();
        var salt = Base64.getDecoder().decode("JvCjRQb/9X8rticKJrDP1uvBCDTz2WEF");
        var iterationCount = 12000;
        var keyLength = 24 * 8;
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
                .generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterationCount, keyLength))
                .getEncoded()));
    }
}
```

Result: dvxvBMpmR6i4D9f1orGx9zUjH9cyv0sM (BellSoft Java 13)

PHP code is

```
<?php
    $algo = "sha256";
    $password = "test";
    $salt = "JvCjRQb/9X8rticKJrDP1uvBCDTz2WEF";
    $count = 12000;
    $key_length = 24;
    echo base64_encode(hash_pbkdf2($algo, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, true));
?>
```

Result: n7znKl8FBPH4ZPbZxPRHPf7vkey+5R2Y (PHP v7.2.24)

I cannot edit PHP code because it is framework code. So, I need to change Java code to match PHP result. How can I change my Java code?

Answer (score 2):

```
function derivateKey($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits)
{
return base64_encode(hash_pbkdf2(
    'sha256',
    $password,
    base64_decode($salt),
    $iterations,
    $keyLengthBits/8,
    true
));
}
```

original idea here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46430311/934967