# PHP implementation of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 from Java

Tags: java, php, cryptography, hmac, sha

I have the following Java implementation of the hashing algorithm:

```java
public String encrypt(@NotNull String value) {
    String ret = null;
    var iv = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // 16 bytes
    var ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    try {
        var factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        var spec = new PBEKeySpec(AUTH_SECRET.toCharArray(),
            SALT.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        var tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        var secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        ret = Base64.getEncoder()
            .encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException |
             InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | BadPaddingException |
             IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while encrypting value: {}", value, e);
    }
    return ret;
}

public String decrypt(@NotNull String value) {
    String ret = null;
    var iv = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    var ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    try {
        var factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        var spec = new PBEKeySpec(AUTH_SECRET.toCharArray(),
            SALT.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        var tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        var secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        var cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        ret = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(value)),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchPaddingException |
             InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | BadPaddingException |
             IllegalBlockSizeException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while decrypting value: {}", value, e);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

After research, I found the following functions, which probably need to be used:
[hash_pbkdf2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)
[hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php)

There is already a thread on this topic: [PHP alternative of "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256" from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429683/php-alternative-of-pbkdf2withhmacsha256-from-java)
However, my implementation seems to be different from the one in the thread.
For example, I have an `AUTH_SECRET` generated with OpenSSL. Where do I have to pass this as a parameter?

This is what I achieved with PHP so far:

```php
function derivate_key($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits): string {
        return hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits / 8, true);
}

function encrypt($plaintext, $key): string {
    $iv = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
    $cipher = "AES-256-CBC";
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv);
    $hmac = hash_hmac("sha256", $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
    return base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);
}
```

Unfortunately, the output value differs from that of the Java implementation

Comment: I strongly recommend against writing your own encryption and hashing implementations, and at the risk of sounding rude: especially if you need to ask about them on Stackoverflow. This is a domain for specialists.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Do you have a recommendation for an implementation which is easy to implement on the part of Java and PHP?

Comment: Note that your implementation is insecure if you use a static salt instead of a random salt of sufficient length. I can't find an `AUTH_KEY` in the code, only an `AUTH_SECRET`. The latter is the password from which the actual key is derived. Please post your most recent PHP code.

Comment: @Isiem I haven't used PHP for anything serious in well over a decade so I'm not qualified to answer

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke - This is AES/CBC with PBKDF2 for key derivation and in that sense not a custom implementation of encryption or hashing.

Comment: @Topaco okay, I was under the impression that the OP wanted to port a Java algorithm to PHP. Might have misinterpreted

Comment: @Topaco I have edited the thread and added the PHP code (which returns a different value than the Java implementation).

Answer (score 0):

So that the PHP code gives the same ciphertext as the Java code, the following is necessary:

- In `encrypt()`, the determination of the HMAC and the concatenation have to be removed, since neither happens in the Java code.
- Instead, `$ciphertext_raw` must be returned (where `$ciphertext_raw` is an odd name, since `openssl_encrypt()` returns the ciphertext Base64 encoded by default).
- The key to be passed to `encrypt()` is to be determined with `derivate_key()`. Note that `$keyLengthBits` and the algorithm must be consistent, e.g. for an n bit key AES-n-CBC must be specified.

Then, if the same values for password, salt, iteration count, and key size are used for both codes, both codes will return the same ciphertext.

Full code and example:

```php
<?php
function derivate_key($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits): string {
    return hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits / 8, true);
}

function encrypt($plaintext, $key): string {
    $iv = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
    $cipher = "AES-256-CBC";
    $ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, 0, $iv);
    //$hmac = hash_hmac("sha256", $ciphertext_raw, $key, true);
    //return base64_encode($iv . $hmac . $ciphertext_raw);
    return $ciphertext_raw;
}

$salt = "This is a test salt";
$password = "This is a test Passphrase";
$iterations = 10000;
$keyLengthBits = 256;

$key = derivate_key($password, $salt, $iterations, $keyLengthBits);
$ciphertext = encrypt("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", $key);
print($ciphertext . PHP_EOL); // cqSHCSOOZlZmugahBVpTusElSEN1gKqiQQDUr1YF1AlLAO466g1/DldwcuoWOjOW
?>
```

which produces the same (Bas64 encoded) ciphertext as the Java code:

```
cqSHCSOOZlZmugahBVpTusElSEN1gKqiQQDUr1YF1AlLAO466g1/DldwcuoWOjOW
```

---

Security:

It looks like you are using a static salt. A static salt is generally problematic (see e.g. [here](https://dchest.com/2020/06/15/does-salt-need-to-be-random-for-password-hashing/)). Because of the static IV there is an additional problem: Since a static salt always generates the same key for the same password, key/IV pairs are reused, which is also insecure (for some algorithms like CTR or GCM even fatal).

For this reason, a random salt of sufficient length should be generated for each encryption here (and in general). The random salt generates different keys, so that even with a static IV there is no reuse of key/IV pairs. The salt is not secret and is passed along with the ciphertext to the decrypting side, typically concatenated.

If you want to avoid the dependence of the IV on the randomness of the salt, the IV can also be generated randomly. The IV is also not secret and is passed together with the salt and ciphertext to the decrypting side, also concatenated.

On the decrypting side the parts can be separated using the known lengths for salt and/or IV.